# How to use share library for GAE modules in Eclipse run time?

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine

I'm using Eclipse Luna with Google Plugin for Eclipse.  I follow instruction from below link to create GAE modules
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/webtoolsplatform

I'm able share source between modules based on http://blog.christoffer.me/post/2011-01-22-share-code-java-eclipse/#.U_N7QfmSyz8

Right now I have 3 modules and I would like to share the common library files (i.e jar files) instead of place them to each module's /WEB-INF/lib.  I had try placed common jar files to /EarContent/lib and add below line to  application.xml:
lib

But it did not work, where ClassNotFoundException is throw during local GAE server start up.  Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved...  I just need to create a 'java build path entries' which point to common class folder and then add it to 'Web Deployment Assembly'

[image]